# WPF MVVM controls sharing info

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm learning WPF and MVVM and trying to stress good design. I have lots of experience with WinForms and C#. This is conceptual so I don't think I need to post code.

I have a xaml Window that manages "Profiles". On the left half is a custom Control treeview bound to a ViewModel that reads a database and creates a heirarchy of profiles. The ViewModel for the individual profiles contains a database ID among other things. The right half is another custom control with a ListView and its own ViewModel that reads the database for individual Profile information.

Both halves work fine independently, but now I want to tie the treeview selection with the listview so that the information in the listview reflects the treeview selection. What is the best way to do this?

The treeview viewmodel provides a profile ID that can be used to lookup profile information in the listview. Again, the goal is to just to tie these two together. I feel like I have a few options:

-The treeview's viewmodel could call a static method in the listview viewmodel that updates the profile.

-The whole page could contain a viewmodel that has member viewmodels for both components.

-I could somehow "route" the treeviewss viewmodel's known selected profile to the listview control in the xaml file.

All of these options feel dirty. Again I'm learning here, and want to stress good design as these little details dictate larger decisions later on.

And ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Prism?  CAL WPF?  If so you might want to consider using Composite Events.  These are events that work across ViewModels, there are also CompositeCommands.

You can set up a composite event like so ...

```
public class ProfileSelectedEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<Profile>
{
}
```

You can then use the EventAggregator to subscribe and publish the composite events.  If your using Prism/CAL for WPF you'll have Unity plugged in, so you can just put IEventAggregator in the constructor of your ViewModel

```
TreeViewViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
```

Then you can publish and subscribe to the Event via the EventAggregator ...

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<ProfileSelectedEvent>().Publish(profile);
```

Subscribe is very similar ... I'm sure you get the idea!

Hope this helps,

Andy

Comment: I am not using Prism/CAL, actually this is the first I've heard of it. Is using it becoming a common trend that I should make a habit of using ... in other words am I entering a world of hurt in trying to learn with just the base WPF installation structure and MVVM structures?

Comment: It just provides a really good framework to build on - heres an MSDN article about it ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx

But what you really want to do is download this and load up the StockTrader app that Microsoft have created as an example ...

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=6DD3D0C1-D5B4-453B-B827-98E162E1BD8D&displaylang=en

That will show you how you can put things together and was how I got started using WPD and MVVM.  Hope this helps ...

Comment: Thanks, Andy. It took me a bit to understand Prism and what it's about. Digging deeper, I using and EventAggregator would accomplish what I want to do. This gives me general direction more than just a line of code. Thanks for your input!